# Extract date out of multiline output in Go

Tags: parsing, go, text

Please see the output of the `net use` command below. Now I want to extract the expiration date out of this piece of text. Unfortunately the `net use` command is unable to output as json, xml or whatever parsble format. Therefore I'm stuck to this text :(. I'm only interested in getting `10-6-2017 6:57:20` and convert it into Golang date format.

The problem: I don't know how to start? First find the row which contains "Password expires"? And then what?

```
User name                    jdoe
Full Name                    John Doe
Comment
User's comment
Country code                 (null)
Account active               Yes
Account expires              Never

Password last set            1-5-2017 6:57:20
Password expires             10-6-2017 6:57:20
Password changeable          1-5-2017 6:57:20
Password required            Yes
User may change password     Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    str := `
User name                    jdoe
Full Name                    John Doe
Comment
User's comment
Country code                 (null)
Account active               Yes
Account expires              Never

Password last set            1-5-2017 6:57:20
Password expires             10-6-2017 6:57:20
Password changeable          1-5-2017 6:57:20
Password required            Yes
User may change password     Yes`

    lines := strings.Split(str, "\n")

    for _, line := range lines {
        if strings.HasPrefix(line, "Password expires") {
            elems := strings.Split(line, " ")
            date := elems[len(elems)-2]
            time := elems[len(elems)-1]
            fmt.Println(date, time)
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use `regex`.